# spark-submit: NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException

Tags: apache-spark, jackson, spark-submit

the method belongs to SparkSession , the name is getOrCreate()

detailed exception is

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.<init>(Ljava/io/Closeable;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.setupModule$(JacksonModule.scala:46)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:17)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:718)
    at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.<init>(JsonProtocol.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.<clinit>(JsonProtocol.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.initEventLog(EventLoggingListener.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:610)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2690)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:949)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:943)
    at com.hiido.server.service.impl.SparkSqlJob.executing(SparkSqlJob.java:56)
    at com.hiido.server.service.impl.SparkSqlJob.main(SparkSqlJob.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:737)
```

Someone said it happened due to version conflict, I disagree.
Because I have checked my spark version, it's spark_core_2.12-3.2.1 and jackson version is 2.12.3 and spark_version is 3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7
I have no idea about this problem.
This problem only happend at spark cluster , when i use local it's ok.
thx.

additional:
this is my pom.xml , I only show my depency , sry

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <geospark.version>1.2.0</geospark.version>
        <spark.compatible.verison>2.3</spark.compatible.verison>
        <!--<spark.version>2.3.4</spark.version>-->
        <spark.version>3.2.1</spark.version>
        <hadoop.version>2.7.2</hadoop.version>
        <geotools.version>19.0</geotools.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.68.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--        <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.4</version>
                </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId> jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId> jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- geospark -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datasyslab</groupId>
            <artifactId>geospark</artifactId>
            <version>${geospark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datasyslab</groupId>
            <artifactId>geospark-sql_${spark.compatible.verison}</artifactId>
            <version>${geospark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datasyslab</groupId>
            <artifactId>geospark-viz_${spark.compatible.verison}</artifactId>
            <version>${geospark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- geospark -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sedona</groupId>
            <artifactId>sedona-core-3.0_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1-incubating</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sedona</groupId>
            <artifactId>sedona-sql-3.0_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1-incubating</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sedona</groupId>
            <artifactId>sedona-viz-3.0_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1-incubating</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datasyslab</groupId>
            <artifactId>sernetcdf</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.3.4</version>-->
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <scope>${dependency.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <scope>${dependency.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-grid</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.locationtech.spatial4j/spatial4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.locationtech.spatial4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>spatial4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JTS is essentially only used for polygons. -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.locationtech.jts/jts-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Where are you calling SparkSession.getOrCreate()? In a java/scala/python file? If so can you share the file and the pom.xml (in case of java) or build.sbt (in case of scala)?

Comment: I have calling SparkSession.getOrCreate() at Java and i will show pom.xml, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the wrong Spark and Hadoop packaging strategy in your Maven pom.xml.

1. Your POM.xml includes many packages that shouldn't be put in 'compile' scope. E.g., spark, and hadoop dependencies. Spark clusters usually have all these libs already. If you mistakenly include them in your jars, it is uncertain that which jackson version will be used. Please change them to 'provided' scope. What Spark and Sedona developers usually do is that, use `compile` scope for local testing and change to `provided` scope when deploy to a cluster.
2. You usually don't need to include Hadoop dependencies since Spark jars come with many Hadoop dependencies. This will lead to many version conflicts in JackSon.
3. Your GeoSpark dependency is wrong. Please remove both your old GeoSpark and Sedona dependecies and follow the instruction here: https://sedona.apache.org/setup/maven-coordinates/#use-sedona-fat-jars

Here is a runnable example of Sedona + Spark project: https://github.com/apache/incubator-sedona/blob/master/examples/sql/build.sbt#L59 . Although it is written in sbt, POM shares the same logic.

Please pay close attention to those `dependency scope` and `exclude` parts.

Comment: thank you,i found it's because of my version is different betwenn of the cluster , i user maven helper add the jar to the cluster's dir .  thank you so much.